# C socket send broke by recv

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I have a C socket client which does the following:

```
if(send(network_socket, message, strlen(message), 0) < 0)
{
    puts("Send failed");
}
```

It works perfectly fine (my server receives the message).
Nonetheless, when I want to hear from the server back, my recv function breaks the previous send !

```
if(send(network_socket, message, strlen(message), 0) < 0)
{
    puts("Send failed");
}

recv(network_socket, &server_reponse, sizeof(server_reponse), 0);
```

I guess it is because of the shared argument ("network_socket").

Could you explain me why this recv breaks the previous send (and how to fix it)?

Comment: Breaks how?  Please create an MCVE ([MCVE]) that shows this breakage.  There shouldn't be an issue, but it is difficult to guess what you've got that could be causing trouble.  You should be testing the result of `recv()` too.  You should be reporting the error to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  It isn't clear that you should expect a response if the `send()` failed.  These may be issues resolved in the MCVE — that's why the MCVE is important.

Comment: Your question is incomplete but I am going to take a stab in the dark and assume that server_response is an array. Therefor &server_reponse is a bad pointer for recv. You should simply use server_reponse (without "&")

Comment: Sockets are bidirectional, there's no interference between `send()` and `recv()`.

Comment: You need to check the return value of recv.